# Scheduling Skype for business meeting programmatically from server

Tags: backend, skype-for-business

I'd like to schedule programmatically a Skype for Business (online) meeting from my app server.
I've been digging around but it seems the only solution is use UCWA https://msdn.microsoft.com/skype/ucwa/DevelopingUCWAApplicationsForSfBOnline, but it seems to work only in web pages while the user is browsing.

Comment: You could write your own wrapper around UCWA and make web requests from any language that understands HTTP/JSON and then you would have more control over where the application could run.

Answer (score 0):

Increasingly shameless self plug - I've written a console-based app that demonstrates how to do this:

[ucwa-sfbo-console](https://github.com/tamhinsf/ucwa-sfbo-console)

You'll need to plug in your own Azure AD environment settings, but the baseline code for creating and deleting a meeting is there for you to adapt to your own needs.